# Woocommerce admin panel - color quantity >2

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I create this message because I can not find my answer ...
I am looking for a way that in woocommerce, when a person orders a quantity greater than 2, the number of the quantity is highlighted in a color.

I put a screenshot to show what screen I'm talking about in woocommerce.

My request is not complicated but I can't find any way to do it...

Thanks in advance

[admin panel order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNJEq.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
    add_action('admin_footer', function () {

        echo <<<'EOT'
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
    var qty_string = $("#order_line_items .quantity .view").html();
    var qty_amount = qty_string.charAt(qty_string.length-3);
    if( qty_amount > 2 ){
     $("#order_line_items .quantity .view").css("color", "red");
    }
    });
</script>
EOT;
    }, 99999);
```

Add the below code to your active theme `functions.php` file

Comment: I just tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work :/

Comment: try `qty_string.charAt(qty_string.length-3);` to `qty_string.charAt(qty_string.length-2);`

Comment: I managed to get the solution, I share it here


`add_action('admin_head', 'add_css_js_to_admin');

function add_css_js_to_admin()
{
    echo "<style>
    .couleur-stock{background-color: red;}
</style>";
    echo "<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('tr.item td.quantity .view').each(function () {
jQuery(this).html(function (index, text) {
if (text.trim() != '<small class=\"times\">×</small> 1') {
jQuery(this).addClass('couleur-stock');
}
});
});
});
</script>";
}`